# App crashes when textview is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent, crash, textview

xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manage_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/redirect_call"
    android:layout_below="@+id/call_forwarding_togglebutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/manage_numbers_label"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:onClick="manage_numbers_onClick"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
//import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void manage_numbers_onClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Manage_numbers.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);

      }  

}
```

When clicked, should navigate to this page.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/set_forward_numbers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/set_forward_numbers_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/set_number_to_receive_image"
    android:text="@string/set_forward_numbers_label"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

This is the java class for next page:

```
package com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
//import android.view.View;
//import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Manage_numbers extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/*public void set_forward_numbers_onClick (View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Manage_numbers.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
  }  

public void set_number_to_receive_onClick (View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Manage_numbers.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
  }  */
}
```

However, whenever I click the textview in the emulator, the app crashes and I have researched on this problem but can't seem to find a solution to solve it. Thanks

These are the logs.

```
01-14 04:40:33.378: I/Choreographer(793): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-14 04:40:33.748: D/gralloc_goldfish(793): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-14 04:40:39.398: D/AndroidRuntime(793): Shutting down VM
01-14 04:40:39.428: W/dalvikvm(793): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  ... 11 more
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall/com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.Manage_numbers}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.MainActivity.manage_numbers_onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  ... 14 more
```

After declaring the Manage_numbers.class in androidmanifest (although I'm not sure did I do correctly). I received these few logs.

```
01-15 03:26:13.488: D/gralloc_goldfish(1610): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-15 03:26:16.638: I/Choreographer(1610): Skipped 117 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-15 03:26:18.528: D/AndroidRuntime(1610): Shutting down VM
01-15 03:26:18.528: W/dalvikvm(1610): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method manage_numbers_onClick(View) in the activity class com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.Manage_numbers for onClick handler on view class android.widget.TextView with id 'manage_number'
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: manage_numbers_onClick [class android.view.View]
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
01-15 03:26:18.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     ... 11 more
01-15 03:26:21.878: I/Choreographer(1633): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-15 03:26:21.898: D/gralloc_goldfish(1633): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

And this is what I declared in androidmanifest.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <activity
        android:name="com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.Manage_numbers"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```

Comment: Problem in `Manage_numbers.class`. Check either it declared in Manifest file or **NPE** in `onCreate()` of it.

Comment: logs please..please post logs that what are you receiving

Comment: these are the Manage_numbers.java                                     Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

Comment: From log traces provided its very clear you havent declared Manage_numbers activity in your AndroidManifest file...

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: My androidmanifest                     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: How do I go about declaring or defining java classes? I have not learnt that somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 01-14 04:40:39.458: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall/com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.Manage_numbers};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

From the above log traces its very clear you haven't declared Manage_numbers activity in your AndroidManifest file.

```
<activity
     android:name="com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.Manage_numbers"
     android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

inside your  `<application>.... </application>` block... Refer here for [better understanding](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: So it means I create another <activity
            android:name="com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.Manage_numbers"
       android:label="@string/app_name">
         </activity> Do I still put in intent filter as well?  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: you are calling Manage_numbers.class through `startActivity(myIntent)` so it is assumed Manage_numbers is an activity i.e it extends Activity. So you have to define it as an activity in your Manifest file.. And **no**... adding intent filter is not required since it is not your main acivity

Comment: Somehow there's another problem. The app doesn't crash anymore, however, when I clicked on the text, it refreshes and when I click it again, the crash message appears. After the crash, it goes back to the same screen again. But the 2nd page never appears.

Comment: @user3197061 Please post what and how you have written your code in onCreate() method.

Comment: @user3197061 you have same layout in both the activities i.e. `R.layout.activity_main` , so you get a feeling that screen has been refreshed, but infact a new activity has been launched....

Comment: @user3197061 So, are you using same layout for both activities ?

Comment: ohhh, but shouldn't the text change? because they have different text and images

Comment: @user3197061 I am not getting you.Please update your new error log and xml file

Comment: @user3197061 try creating new layout say layout_second.xml in your layout folder with some new fields other than those in activity_main layout.. and then call setContentView(R.layout.layout_second); in Manage_numbers class and see the difference..

Comment: Thanks alot everyone! I managed to navigate around and learn the logic. Thanks again! esp @CRUSADER

Answer (score 1):

Is `Manage_numbers.class` defined in the manifest? And is it not null?

Are you inflating the correct layout in MainActivity?

You need to post your logcat for a better specific answer.

Comment: sorry, but how do I define it in manifest. I'm abit confused because I  just started learning.  
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hihi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>